# Creating a dataframe by using row numbers of other data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, dplyr, row-number

I would like to know that whether there is a way in R for using datasets with similar names. For example:

I have eight datasets named `cars_1995`, `cars_new_1995`, `cars_1996`, `cars_new_1996`, `cars_1997`, `cars_new_1997`, `cars_1998` and `cars_new_1998` and they have different dimensions but only thing that I want to use is their row numbers.

So I want to create a new data frame and rownames will be the years (1995,1996,1997,1998) and colnames will be the groups (`cars`, `cars_new`). the dimension of the data frame will be 4:2. The values of the dataframe will be the rownumbers such as:

```
       Cars  Cars_new
  1995  25  76 
  1996  38  35 
  1997  87  49 
  1998  34  50
```

First question is, in the R, is there a way to use the names of dataframes like I need to take row numbers of all data frames from 1995 to 1999 (one column for `cars_YEAR`, the other column for `cars_YEAR_new`). By the way only year indicator is the names of the data frames.

I'm OK with how to build a data frame or how to get the rownumbers (`nrow`) However, I haven't figured out how to pull all datasets by just using embed years of the dataframes' names consecutively.So it would be great how to get all `cars_YEAR` datasets row numbers by using the year extension in the datasets names.

Comment: in the datasets you have, are the row names now: Cars_1995 etc... or is that a column in the dataframe?

Comment: Hey, dataset itself is named Cars_1995, so I have 3 more datasets like cars_1996 so on and I want to use names of the datasets (cars_1995 so on) in an automatized way. I have to find a command or create a function which sees the last four digit of the dataset names as actually years and process them in the right order such as ---> Ok take the cars_1995 rownumber and print it to [1,1], then take the cars_1995_New and print the rownumber in the second column first row. We are done with 1995. Find the next year which is cars_1996 do the same thing for both cars_1996 and cars_1996_new, so on.

Comment: what file format are the datasets in?

Comment: All are dataframes.

Comment: Yes. This is possible. You'll want to check out the get function in base R. That will let you retrieve objects by character name. Once you have that, you can use lapply over your numbers to build a data structure for each year and bind.rows to push the results together into the same data.frame.  That is probably better than loading three packages, but YMMV - especially if you already use those packages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution using `stringr` + `dplyr` + `tidyr`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

ls() %>%
  str_extract("^cars_\\d{4}.*") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mget(envir = globalenv()) %>%
  lapply(nrow) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  mutate(key = str_replace(key, "(\\d{4})_(.+)", "\\2_\\1")) %>%
  separate(key, c("key", "year"), "_(?=\\d)") %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

**Result:**

```
  year cars cars_new
1 1995  114      102
2 1996  113       61
3 1997  168      186
4 1998  196       68
```

**Notes:**

1. `ls()` is handy for this example as it can extract all object names in the global environment.
2. Using `str_extract`, I extracted only object names that starts with `cars_[4 digits]` then fed the result into `mget`
3. `mget` takes a vector of character object names and returns the values from a specified environment in a named list
4. `lapply` is used to extract row numbers in each element (dataset) of the list. This is then converted to a data.frame with each column corresponding to a row number.
5. `gather` reshapes the data.frame from wide to long format.
6. The regular expression in `mutate` and `separate` are respectively to change names from `cars_1995_news` to `cars_new_1995` and separate into a column of `cars_new` and `year`
7. The final `spread` reshapes the data.frame to the desired format.

**Note about data:**

I used `rnorm` and `sample` to create the toy datasets and *did not* set a seed for each of them. This means you will *not* get the same resulting data.frame as what I have here. This is ok as what the row numbers actually are is not important to solve OP's problem.

**Data:**

```
# Create sample datasets
cars_1995 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1995_new = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1996 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1996_new = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1997 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1997_new = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1998 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1998_new = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
```

### Edits (dataset names from `cars_YEAR_new` to `cars_new_YEAR`):

```
ls() %>%
  str_extract("^cars_(new_)*\\d{4}") %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  mget(envir = globalenv()) %>%
  lapply(nrow) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  separate(key, c("key", "year"), "_(?=\\d)") %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

With the new dataset names, the `mutate` + `str_replace` step can be removed, and the `str_extract` step also has to be changed, since the pattern is now different.

**New Data:**

```
# Create sample datasets
cars_1995 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_new_1995 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1996 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_new_1996 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1997 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_new_1997 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_1998 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
cars_new_1998 = data.frame(A = rnorm(sample(50:200, 1)))
```

Comment: It seems like I wrote something wrong in my question. I actually have the data sets like cars_new_YEAR format. I realised that when I read your explanation 6th step. So sorry for that, I've changed it right away. However, when I excluded that command (mutate), still I have some problems which says object "key" not found as an error. Totally made sense though, since you defined the key inside the mutate(). Now I'm trying to figure out how to define key by not using "str_replace", since I dont need to replace the strings. However so far, I really couldn't get anything but errors. Sorry again!

Comment: @DSA Simple changes, but in addition to removing the `mutate` step, you also have to adjust the regex in the `str_extract` step. See edits.

Comment: I guess one should know better about those escape chars to see the inner of the code. However, thanks a lot. Now it seems it's working now!

Comment: @DSA I think you might be talking about the "\\" chars. In R regex, the "\" char also has to be escaped, otherwise it will be treated as an "escape character". This is why there are two dashes whenever I want to use _one dash_ for a "\d" match.

Comment: The downvoter seems to think that there is a problem with my answer. Is there anything I can do to improve/fix it?

Comment: That is pretty weird because it's working great on my data. That might be probably, if somebody has the same issue, they can't get the result as they wanted. Because the code print the result in console, however one should easily convert the result as a datafile. That's the only thing in my mind.